# Como faço para mostrar uma imagem de acordo com determinado Número sendo que este número é pelo random no python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagem, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import cv2

def showfig(image, ucmap):
    imgplot=plt.imshow(image, ucmap)
img0 = cv2.imread("zero.jpg",0)
img1 = cv2.imread("um.jpg",0)

from random import randint  #gerar número aleatório, ou seja, randomizar número inteiro
from time import sleep 

computador = randint(0,9) #Faz o computador pensar
print('-=-' * 20) #Para definição de começo da pergunta do computador
print('Vou pensar em um número entre 0 e 9. Tente adivinhar...')
print('-=-' * 20) #Para definição de começo da pergunta do computador
jogador = int(input('Em que número eu pensei?')) #jogador tenta adivinhar
print('Processando...')
sleep(3) 

jogador = 0 
computador = 0

if jogador == computador:

    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.title('Imagem de Entrada')
    showfig(img0, "gray")
    print('Parabéns: você ganhou!')

else:
    print('Ganhei: Eu pensei no número {} e não {}!'.format(computador, jogador))

jogador = 1
computador = 1

if jogador == computador:

    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.title('Imagem de Entrada')
    showfig(img1, "gray")
    print('Parabéns: você ganhou!')

else:
    print('Ganhei: Eu pensei no número {} e não {}!'.format(computador, jogador))
```

Comment: Oi Julia, pode ser mais especifica? Você já tentou algo? Está tendo algum código de erro como retorno? Acho que pode ser interessante também mostrar como está sua pasta de arquivos, para saber se o caminho que está puxando a imagem está correto.

Comment: Olá. Identifiquei e já foi corrigido, obrigada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de usar uma variável para cada imagem, use uma estrutura indexável, como listas ou dicionários. Para números a partir do zero, uma lista serviria, mas eu prefiro usar dicionários, para o caso de precisar de mais imagens que não são números depois:

```
imgs = {
    0: cv2.imread("zero.jpg", 0),
    1: cv2.imread("um.jpg", 0),
}
```

Aí depois na hora de mostrar a imagem, é só usar esse dicionário para referenciar a imagem certa de acordo com o número sorteado:

```
computador = randint(0, 9)
...
showfig(imgs[computador], "gray")
```

Comment: , o primeiro método eu usei, o segundo eu usei parecido, mas deu certo. Obrigada!

Comment: @JuliaOliveira Que bom que conseguiu! Se a minha resposta resolveu, considere marcá-la como aceita, para fechar a pergunta. Se quiser compartilhar o que você fez de diferente, posso editar a resposta para que fique mais completa.